# Try and catch alternative

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, autoit

Is there an alternative to Try and Catch in AutoIt? I wonder if there is something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists no try-catch-construct in AutoIt. You have to use [the `@error` macro](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm):

```
call_your_function_here()
If @error Then
    ;do your error stuff
Else
    ;do your program stuff
EndIf
```